# is there any way to filter array with a combination of key value PHP

Tags: php

how can i filter an array using key value combination.

let array is

```
a=>1
a=>2
a=>3

b=>4
c=>5
```

is there any function to search to filter combination of key(a) and value(1)

In php any function there. array_map..or array_seacrh

Comment: It depends how you phrase it. Your example is not so good because in an array, **a key is unique**. You will always only have one value per key. Seeing it this way, you might just want to filter the array by the key. **But** you can also say *I want to filter the array be the key **only** if the value is ...*. Then your question makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine array_filter() with array_walk()... the latter does pass both key and value to the callback function

Answer (score 0):

Not a single function, but an array key must be unique, so you could do something like..

```
if (isset($array['a'] == 1))
```

... But I doubt that is way you want to know.. Could you be a bit more specific?